# Displaying language labels in sidebar facets

Tags: xslt, internationalization, xslt-1.0, dspace

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31598315/1919069) question a few days ago regarding on how to display the language labels in item view instead of its ISO version. How to apply these in sidebar facets and its search filters? I can't find the xslt for generating the displayed values in the sidebar facets.

[image: Sidebar facet of language]

In the image above, I would like to change the displayed values into:

```
English (5325)
French (432)
Chinese (8)
Khmer (5)
Japanese (2)
```

And then when clicking for example the sidebar facet for French, the displayed value in the search filter should be `Language Equals French` and not like the image below (`Language Equals fr`):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**What I have tried**

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do this so any advice would be appreciated.

```
<xsl:template
        match="dri:list[@n='language']/dri:item/dri:xref/text()
        | dri:list[@id='aspect.discovery.SidebarFacetsTransformer.list.language']/dri:item/text()
        | dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SearchFacetFilter.div.browse-by-language-results']/dri:table/dri:row/dri:cell/dri:xref/text()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(name()='head')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="language">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,' (')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(util:isoLanguageToDisplay($language),' (', substring-after(.,'('))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The language labels of the dc.language.iso in my sidebar facets is now displaying properly both in the home page and search results.

[image]

When clicking `View More`:

[image]

My only problem now is this:

[image]

I don't know how to override the advanced search filters or if this is even possible.

Comment: I am missing something about your question. What is the tool or environment?  What piece of software displays the "Filters" UI, for which you are giving us pictures?