# How to access or retrieve mets content of an item from another item?

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

My use case is I have an item that has a link in another item. For example, item `123456789/152` has a metadata field `dc.relation.hasversion=123456789/717`. Within the item view of `123456789/152`, how can I retrieve the values of the metadata of `123456789/717`? For example, I want to retrieve the `dc.language.iso` value of `123456789/717` from `123456789/152`.

I looked at the **Related items** feature in DSpace but I don't know how the metadata displayed in the **Related items** list were pulled from the items in that list.

I am using **DSpace Version 5.3 Mirage 2 Theme**.

**EDIT**

Based on [schweerelos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72625/schweerelos) answer, below is my actual code. I am using a custom metadata field `dc.relation.languageVersion`. Basically, I want to link to that other version but instead of displaying the value, I will display the `dc.language.iso` of the other version in my `item-view.xsl`. I've incorporated the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31598315/1919069) of [schweerelos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72625/schweerelos) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593065/1919069) in the code but it is *just displaying the value* of `dc.relation.languageVersion`. Sample values of `dc.relation.languageVersion` are `10665.1/9843`; `10665.1/9844` ie not the complete URI but just the handle.

Thanks in advance!

**Actual code**

```
<xsl:template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-other-language">
    <xsl:if test="dim:field[@element='relation' and @qualifier='languageVersion' and descendant::text()]">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-print-4 item-page-field-wrapper">
            <h5><i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-languageVersion</i18n:text></h5>
            <span>
                <xsl:for-each select="dim:field[@element='relation' and @qualifier='languageVersion']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates  select="./node()" mode="showRelatedLang"/>
                    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::dim:field[@element='relation' and @qualifier='languageVersion']) != 0">
                        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </span>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dim:field[@element='relation' and @qualifier='languageVersion' and descendant::text()]" mode="showRelatedLang">
    <xsl:variable name="otherItemMetadataURL">
        <xsl:text>cocoon:/metadata/handle/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>/mets.xml</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($otherItemMetadataURL)" mode="showLang"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dim:field[@element='language' and @qualifier='iso' and descendant::text()]" mode="showLang">
    <xsl:value-of select="util:isoLanguageToDisplay(node())"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related items feature uses the Discovery solr index, where "relatedness" is calculated by comparing metadata. The related items' metadata also comes from the solr index, so not something you can re-use easily for your purpose.

You're not saying what DSpace UI variant you're using -- from your other questions I'm assuming XMLUI (your questions might be even more helpful for other Stack Overflow users if you included your DSpace version + UI variant every time).

To retrieve the metadata of an item whose handle you know, use the `document()` function to load that item's mets file. You can then apply templates to the whole thing or to specific metadata fields.

Something like this (totally untested, you will probably have to modify this to make it actually work):

Say your `item-view.xsl` has templates like this (and code to ensure the template is actually called):

```
<xsl:template match="dim:field[@element='relation' and @qualifier='hasversion' and descendant::text()]" mode="showRelatedLang">        
    <xsl:variable name="otherItemMetadataURL">        
        <xsl:text>cocoon://metadata/handle/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>/mets.xml</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>        
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($otherItemMetadataURL)" mode="showLang"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dim:field[@element='language' and @qualifier='iso' and descendant::text()]" mode="showLang">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template reads the handle from the first item's dc.relation.hasversion, then constructs the URL to the second item's mets file and loads the mets file. It then calls the second template to the result of loading the second item's mets file. The second template reads the value from dc.language.iso; because it's called on the result of the `document()` call, this will select the *second* item's language.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I updated my post to include DSpace version and theme and the actual code that I tried. I may be doing something wrong in my code because the result is not I expected to be. I suspect the metadata of the second item is not properly retrieved. Please advice what is wrong in my code and if I missed something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I probably stuffed up something in my sample code, sorry. I'll see if I can look into this later today. In the meantime, you could try putting a comment before the document() call to see what otherItemMetadataURL actually contains, like here https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl#L163 -- it will put an HTML comment into your page that you can see with "view source".

Comment: Hi Andrea! Thank you so much for your help. I now know why the metadata of the second item is not retrieved. There's a missing `/` in the `<xsl:text>cocoon:/metadata/handle/</xsl:text>`. It should be `<xsl:text>cocoon://metadata/handle/</xsl:text>`. I almost gave up on this. :) Whew! Cheers!!!

Comment: Sorry and I'm very glad to hear you got there in the end -- _and_ now you have another item in your DSpace XSL debugging toolbox ;) I've added the extra `/` to my answer, thanks for that.